# Is there assignment expression for Java like Walrus operator in Python

Tags: java

In Python, you can assign a value to a variable and return it at the same time like this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
if (n := len(a)) > 3: 
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 3)")
```

Is there any way to do this in Java?

Comment: I suspect that the distinction here is not "assigning" and "returning" but rather _declaring_ (or possibly just _identifying) a new variable. In Java (and I believe in Python), assignments are already all expressions that evaluate to (not return) the assigned value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no separate operator, but you can definitely do that. You have to declare the variable outside of the if-condition, though:

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int n;
if ((n = a.length) > 3) {
    System.out.println("List is too long (" + n + " elements, expected <= 3)");
}
```

Comment: I think that this will raise a flag in at least some linters.

Comment: True, it is common practice in _some_ situations though, e.g. reading a file with a buffered reader `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` and similar.